# Rendering component after onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I want to render my data after button click. I use the condition rendering in my component and create a boolean variable in state object. After button clicked variable is changed and (as I expected) my data was renderered. But nothing happens. I know that this is a basic mistake.

```
class SortingMyArray extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            addcomments: addcomments,
            isClicked : false
        }

     //   this.sortBy = this.sortBy.bind(this)
    }

    sortBy() {
            let sortedComments = [...this.state.addcomments].sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));
            this.setState({
            addcomments: sortedComments,
            isClicked : true
           })
            console.log(this.state.isClicked)
    }

  render(){
            return(
                  <div>
                        <div>
                           <button
                           onClick={() => this.sortBy() }>AdditionalCommentaries
                           </button>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                )
            if (this.state.isClicked){
                return(
                    <div>
                            <div>
                             <AddComments addcomments = {this.state.addcomments} />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }

            }
}

export default SortingMyArray;
```

Comment: All answers below are good.
I would like to make a suggestion, which would make your life a lot easier in the long run: Use and follow the up to date documentation. The classical approach to react is very rigid and cumbersome.

The only reason you have a class right now, instead of a functional component is because of the local state management. Well, take a look at hooks and be enlightened ;) https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your **render** method since part of code is unreachable, also you don't need to use IF sentence, you can use [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) **&&** to ask if isClicked is true to return **AddComments** component.

> You need to install eslinter in your code editor, this can you help to detect this type 
>   errors or others
>
> [image]

**RENDER METHOD:**

```
render() {

//You can destructuring object, in this case your state is the object
const { isClicked, addcomments } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.sortBy()}>AdditionalCommentaries</button>
    </div>

    {isClicked && (
      <div>
        <AddComments addcomments={addcomments} />
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have more than one return inside render method. Instead try this:

Note: **There is no if-else statement in JSX but we use the one bellow**

```
render(){
    return(

        <div>
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.sortBy() }>AdditionalCommentaries
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {
            this.state.isClicked
            &&
            <div>
                <div>
                    <AddComments addcomments = {this.state.addcomments} />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is unreachable by the program since it is placed after `return`. You should not have two returns.

```
if (this.state.isClicked){
   return (
      <div>
         <div>
            <AddComments 
               addcomments={this.state.addcomments} 
            />
         </div>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Also, your conditional statement is not valid JSX. Your render method should look something like this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.sortBy()}>
                 AdditionalCommentaries
              </button>
           </div>
           {this.state.isClicked && (
              <div>
                 <div>
                    <AddComments 
                       addcomment={this.state.addcomments} 
                    />
                 </div>
              </div>
           )}
        </div>
    )
}
```